# How to create 4 ArrayList Objects from 1 using iterators (for each)

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator, playing-cards

I essentially have a deck of 52 cards and wanted to know how to deal the cards to 4 hands. 
For example so that if it were a real game of cards and each player had a hand, their hand would have 52/4 (13) cards.

I have created the deck and hand classes and produced the constructors so they are initialised properly, but how would I use iterators to deal each card to each hand in turn

I have looked at iterators and could not figure out an appropriate application

Below are the constructors of classes deck and hand

```
private ArrayList<Card> deck;

    public Deck() {
        deck = new ArrayList<>(52);
        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
            deck.add(new Card(value, suit);
    }
```

---

```
private ArrayList<Card> hand;

    public Hand() {
        hand = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

Comment: Post the code you have.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need to iterate. You can use `subList` for that.

```
Collections.shuffle(deck);
List<Card> hand1 = deck.subList(0, 13);
List<Card> hand2 = deck.subList(13, 26);
List<Card> hand3 = deck.subList(26, 39);
List<Card> hand4 = deck.subList(39, 52);
```

This can be generalized in a method that returns a `List<List<Card>>` with a loop.

Comment: This is very risky. I'd do `new ArrayList<Card>(deck.subList(0, 13));` instead. Otherwise innocent looking code like `hand1.remove(0); System.out.println(hand2);` is going to throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int cards = 52;
int players = 4;
int hand = new int[players][cards];


int curPlayer = 0;
round = 0;
while(cards != 0){ 
  hand[curPlayer][round] = GetCardFromDeck();
  if(curPlayer == players){
    curPlayer = 0;
  }
  cards--;
  round++;
}
```

Comment: If you did it like this, would it not be better to make this a bit more OO?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know his object structure. I just wanted to give him the logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you must do it with Iterator one way would be like this:

```
    List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>(); //populate your deck here
    Collections.shuffle(deck);
    Iterator<Card> iter = deck.iterator();

    List<Card> hand1 = new ArrayList<Card>();
    List<Card> hand2 = new ArrayList<Card>();
    List<Card> hand3 = new ArrayList<Card>();
    List<Card> hand4 = new ArrayList<Card>();

    Card c = null;
    while (true) {
        if (iter.hasNext()) {
            c = iter.next();
            hand1.add(c);
        } else {
            break;
        }
        if (iter.hasNext()) {
            c = iter.next();
            hand2.add(c);
        } else {
            break;
        }
        if (iter.hasNext()) {
            c = iter.next();
            hand3.add(c);
        } else {
            break;
        }
        if (iter.hasNext()) {
            c = iter.next();
            hand4.add(c);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
```